# VMware & windows server 2008

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, vmware-workstation

I was installing my active directory on VMware and I wanted to assign a static IP for my virtual machine.

I did so,  but in dcpromo, a yellow warning poped up saying that my IP is not static .

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check:

1. Are there possibly multiple NICs for that VM? Note that if you created and then deleted multiple network adapters, they are not actually deleted, as they remain in registry. To remove, start regedit and delete any unwanted NICs: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards\. You can tell which reg key is which, based on the description.
2. Make sure that in the VM's IP4 network settings, the DNS server is pointing to itself.